# Google Charts interactive API custom axis label

Tags: google-visualization

I am using Google Charts Interactive API and I need to format the axis labels on Y-Axis with custom labels.

I am using LineCharts and this is my code...

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Email-id');<br>enter code here
            data.addColumn('number', 'Last Replied');
            data.addRows(msg.UserLastReplied.length);

    for ( var j = 0; j < msg.UserLastReplied.length; j++) {
        data.setValue(j, 0, msg.UserLastReplied[j].email_id);
        data.setValue(j, 1, parseInt(msg.UserLastReplied[j].msec));
    }
```

I need to replace the labels on Y axis i.e. parseInt(msg.UserLastReplied[j].msec) with another label like msg.UserLastReplied[j].timestamp which is basically a string representing the actual value of msec.

Can some one suggest me how to do this in google charts interactive api?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this would help you [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters) and here is an example that uses it [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Labels)